# Add all files in folder as content "Copy if newer"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a folder witch I want to add to my project, I copy pasted the whole folder into the solution, but now I need to do manually to all this files "Copy if newer" it there a simpler way to to that? this folder contains subfolders with thowsens of files.

[image]

Comment: Use Shift+Click to select multiple files.  Thousands, hmm, that stops being useful.

Comment: @HansPassant That solution is fine only for files in specific directory, but if there is sub directoty tere is no option to select "copy is newer"

Comment: There are a number of possible ways, and probably none of them the "click here once" that you'd like. IMHO, with that many files, you may want instead to archive them and add them as a single resource to the output directory (or even better, as a resource). It's simple enough to extract the files as needed at runtime. Alternatively, you might want to hand-edit the .csproj file and use search/replace to change the option on all the files at once.